# ios - how can i insert a native view behind the webview in a phonegap/cordova plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm writing a Phonegap/Cordova plugin that needs to insert a native UIView **behind** the webView that Cordova provides. I've tried doing the following:

```
[self.webView.superview insertSubview:myView belowSubview:self.webView];
```

and

```
[self.webView.superview addSubview:myView];
```

Both of these added myView on top of the webView.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
[self.webView.superview addSubview:myView];
[self.webView.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
```

Comment: Is this still relevent for 2017 / Cordova 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
[self.webView.superview insertSubview:myView belowSubview:webView];
```

**Additional Notes:**

If you wish to set the webView as transparent, so that you can overlay html elements on top of the native view for example, set this right after the line above:

```
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And in MainViewController.m, uncomment the block of code for webViewDidStartLoad() and add the below:

```
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Note that both lines must be at the right place for it to work. setOpaque must be done before cordova adds the html elements, while setBackgroundColor must be done after.

Comment: Is this still relevent for 2017 / Cordova 7?